# JSON response not mapped to JSONObject in android

Tags: android, json, wcf

I'm trying to read GET JSON response from android App, Server is WCF web service implemented in ASP .net

```
[OperationContract(Name = "Employee")]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "person/{name}")]
Person GetPersonData(string name);
```

Here is the response from the browser:

> {"EmployeeResult":{"Age":31,"Name":"testuser"}}

1. How can I make this as :

> {"Employee":{"Age":31,"Name":"testuser"}}

2. I tried use below code to extract Age and Name in android app

   > ```
   > JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
   > JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("EmployeeResult");
   > for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
   >      JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
   >      int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("Age").toString());
   >       String name = jsonObject.optString("Name").toString();
   >                           Log.i("JsonClient", "Age: "+id+" Name: "+name);
   >  }
   > ```

jsonArray is null why? is JSON not formatted correctly? jsonRootObject is not null and jsonStr has correct response text

Thanks

Comment: Please look into json syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

Comment: JSON objects are written inside curly braces. and JSON arrays are written inside square brackets. How to generate square brackets for JSON arrays and how to remove "Result" string from response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well **EmployeeResult** is not JsonArray It is JsonObject

paste your json response in the below link

http://json.parser.online.fr/

```
JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONObject  EmployeeResultJsonObject = jsonRootObject.getJSONObject("EmployeeResult");

 int id = EmployeeResultJsonObject.getInt("age");
 String name = EmployeeResultJsonObject.getString("Name");
 Log.i("JsonClient", "Age: "+id+" Name: "+name);
```

Answer (score 1):

`EmployeeResult` is not a `JSONArray`, it is `JSONObject`.

Change it to

```
JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONObject employeeResult = jsonObject.getJSONObject("EmployeeResult");
String name = employeeResult.getString("Name");
int age = employeeResult.getInt("Age");
```

Comment: Solution is Correct, Just change syntax